# How do I use protocol-relative urls (starts with //) in Plone and/or TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, plone

I would like to use protocol-relative URLs in Plone's TinyMCE e.g. //www.example.org points to http or https://example.org depending on which was used to access the page. Unfortunately they get filtered out or changed. Is there a toggle or setting to allow these?

Comment: I don't think there is a setting for this -- it's hidden somewhere in the filter chain. (If you set the type of the page to "Plone Output Filters HTML", the user-visibility of which seems like a security bug to me in the first place, your link stays intact.)

Comment: OK, I tentatively take that back -- it appears that TinyMCE's submit already sends the mangled link. I got as far as suspecting tinyMCE.triggerSave, but that's hidden in 400k of minified Javascript, so, errr, not pursuing that.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for not using relative paths?

Comment: Yes. It's a link to another site!

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE has a setting 'convert_urls' (default true) that if changed to false would allow relative URLs. (The same setting may also allow common and undesirable browser URL-mangling to get through.)

There isn't a setting for this in Plone. You would just have to edit or override the bit of JavaScript that initializes TinyMCE to pass the setting.

Comment: You can change this setting in `Products/TinyMCE/utility.py`. See this [patch](https://github.com/jnachtigall/Products.TinyMCE/commit/c3af71267b76cb7d2da5b08165dd7c93d1fe21a1) on how this can be done (this patch is about `relative_urls` option but the idea is the same).